# Can't resolve a dependency with camera_umd that wants a specific version (Ubuntu ARM)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ros-groovy-camera-umd but I am having a problem where it says I have the dependency installed but it isn't exactly the right version.  I am running Ubuntu ARM (Linaro) on an ODROID U2 and I have added the appropriate repositories from the tutorial on how to set up ROS on ARM.

```
 linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo aptitude install ros-groovy-camera-umd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-groovy-camera-umd{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 332 not upgraded.
Need to get 2168 kB of archives. After unpacking 6409 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-camera-umd : Depends: ros-groovy-image-common (= 1.10.3-0precise-20130418-2026-+0000) but 1.10.3-0precise-20130426-1422-+0000 is installed.
                         Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.14-0precise-20130401-1554-+0000) but 1.7.14-0precise-20130426-1327-+0000 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     ros-groovy-camera-umd [Not Installed]              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***
```

I have seen other posts where they get this kind of version error (e.g. Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.14-0precise-20130401-1554-+0000) but 1.7.14-0precise-20130426-1327-+0000 is installed.) but in those cases it seems to be a general problem that affects many packages and that isn't the case here.  Most everything, including things like ros-groovy-ros-base, install fine.  Any help regarding a way to resolve this problem to allow camera_umd to be installed would be appreciated and I would be happy to post any additional information that is needed.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69043/can%27t-resolve-a-dependency-with-camera_umd-that-wants-a-specific-version-(ubuntu-arm)/) by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up solving it by git cloning the package and compiling from source.  It didn't really fix the problem with finding dependencies but it did allow the package to compile and run.

---

Originally posted by [MD_MD](https://answers.ros.org/users/5584/md_md/) with karma: 31 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccostes](https://answers.ros.org/users/8881/ccostes/) on 2013-11-25**:
Did you have any compile issues when building the uvc_camera node? I'm getting a compile error referring to an undefined reference to something related to YAML.
Full Error:

Linking CXX executable /home/linaro/ros/devel/lib/uvc_camera/uvc_camera_node
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so: undefined reference to `YAML::Emitter::PostWriteStreamable(std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so: undefined reference to` YAML::Emitter::PreWriteStreamable(std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&)'